# Getting median and 95th percentile statistics in SAS over multiple variables

Tags: sas, mean, median

I am currently trying to extract a median and 95th percentile out of a dataset for part of my work in SAS 9.4, however I cannot find either a simple, or working method of doing so. I have data in the form of:

```
NAME TREATMENT DATE week0 week1 week2 week3 week4 week5 week6 week7    
CCG1 Treatment1 APR16 1 1 3 2 4 0 0 0    
CCG1 Treatment2 APR16 0 0 2 12 0 3 5 0
```

What I want to be able to do is find the median number of weeks required for a treatment as well as the 95th centile of treatment times.

I've looked at both proc means and univariate however whatever I try tends to try to do the statistics in vertical calculations as opposed to across the horizontal. I did look at transpose also but again, it didn't quite do it as it lost the data in the process. A sample of the dataset is as follows. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try proc means.

Comment: How many week fields per row? is it seven fixed weeks? Please add an example of how you want your output to look like. I'll put the code for you in the answer.

Comment: There are 53 week rows in total. I am working with the commissioner tab of the admitted commissioner files found here https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/statistical-work-areas/rtt-waiting-times/rtt-data-2016-17/

Answer (score 3):

Transpose your data using by-groups. This will make it much easier to work with.

```
proc transpose data=have
               out=want(rename=(COL1 = Value) )
               name=week
               ;

    by Name Treatment Date;

    var week0-week7;
run;

proc means data=want median p95;
    by Name Treatment Date;
    var value;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you have fixed number of columns (weeks) per row; you can use the `Mean()` & `median()` functions

Input Data:

```
data have;
length TREATMENT $10;
input NAME $ TREATMENT $ DATE $ week0 week1 week2 week3 week4 week5 week6 week7;
datalines;
CCG1 Treatment1 APR16 1 1 3 2 4 0 0 0
CCG1 Treatment2 APR16 0 0 2 12 0 3 5 0
;
run;
```

Code:

```
data want;
set have;
keep NAME TREATMENT DATE MEDIAN MEAN;
MEDIAN=median(week0 ,week1 ,week2, week3 ,week4, week5, week6, week7);
MEAN=mean(week0 ,week1 ,week2, week3 ,week4, week5, week6, week7);
run;
```

Output:

```
TREATMENT=Treatment1 NAME=CCG1 DATE=APR16 MEDIAN=1 MEAN=1.375 
TREATMENT=Treatment2 NAME=CCG1 DATE=APR16 MEDIAN=1 MEAN=2.75
```

Comment: This assumes each treatment has a single line, which is what the OP has shown but would be a really weird way to have this data. Most likely its going to be one person, per treatment, per row and then this wouldn't work.  Nothing wrong with the answer though, if the assumption that one line per treatment is correct.

Comment: This seemed to work but on closer inspection, it gives you the median of the values in the row. What I probably didn't make clear is that I want the median week likely to be treated. I've tried putting the week variables into an array and multiplying the values with the index number of the week in the array. This didn't give me what was needed either.

Answer (score 0):

After computing `median` iterate over the week values to find the first one that is nearest.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array x week:;

  median = median(of x(*));

  diff = 1e12;
  do i = 1 to dim(x);
    p = x(i);
    if abs(p-median) < diff then do;
      first_var_nearest_median = vname(x(i));
      diff = abs(p-median);
    end;
  end;  
run;
```

One alternative, as when there are ties, is to quicksort a copy of the array and a parallel 'index' array. Then select the central most element to get the index of the median variable and from that the variable name.  See ["QuickSorting An Array" Paul M. Dorfman](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi26/p096-26.pdf) from SUGI 26 Coders Corner.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array x week:;

  median = median(of x(*));

  array _xcopy(8) _temporary_;
  array _index(8) _temporary_;

  do i = 1 to dim(x);
    _xcopy(i) = x(i);
    _index(i) = i;
  end;

  %qsort (arr=_xcopy _index)

  put _xcopy(4)= _xcopy(5)=;
  put _index(4)= _index(5)=/;

  ix4 = _index(4);
  ix5 = _index(5);

  %* 4 and 5 are the median contributors;
  week_val_at_sorted_position_4 = x(ix4);
  week_var_at_sorted_position_4 = vname(x(ix4));
  week_val_at_sorted_position_5 = x(ix5);
  week_var_at_sorted_position_5 = vname(x(ix5));

  drop i ix:;
run;
```

Paul's quicksort macro

```
%Macro Qsort (
   Arr =                        /* Parallel array name list */
 , By  = %QScan(&Arr,1,%Str( )) /* Key array name           */
 , Seq = A                      /* Seq=D for descending     */
 , LB  = Lbound(&By)            /* Lower bound to sort      */
 , HB  = Hbound(&By)            /* Upper bound to sort      */
 , M   = 9                      /* Tuning range: [1:15]     */
    );

 /*==================================================================+
 | Name:    Qsort.                                                   |
 |===================================================================|
 | Developer: Paul M. Dorfman.                                       |
 |===================================================================|
 | Function: Sort array in place via the QuickSort algorithm.        |
 |===================================================================|
 | General:                                                          |
 |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | Qsort is a macro call routine designed to be invoked from within  |
 | a DATA step to sort a single-subscripted array or a parallel list |
 | of N arrays using one array as a key. The array(s) can be arrays  |
 | SAS variables or a temporary array; numeric or character. Arrays  |
 | in the list do not have to be the same type and/or item length.   |
 |                                                                   |
 | The kernel of the routine is a DATA step implementation of the    |
 | QuickSort algorithm (C.A.R. Hoare, 1960). Final ordering is done  |
 | by a single sweep of the modified insertion sort after quicksort  |
 | has reduced all array subpartitions to no more than &M items.     |
 |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | Performance:                                                      |
 |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | Run-time increases as N*log2(N), where N is the number of array   |
 | elements to be sorted. As a benchmark, a random numeric temporary |
 | array is sorted into ascending order in lt 1 CPU sec under OS/390 |
 | IBM model 9672 R36 running SAS version 8.0.                       |
 |===================================================================|
 | Usage examples:                                                   |
 |===================================================================|
 | 1. Sorting entire array A ascending (semicolon is optional):      |
 |                                                                   |
 |    %Qsort (Arr=A, Seq=a);                                         |
 |                                                                   |
 |    or simply, using Seq=a default,                                |
 |                                                                   |
 |    %Qsort (Arr=A);                                                |
 |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | 2. Sorting entire array B descending:                             |
 |                                                                   |
 |    %Qsort (Arr=B, Seq=d);                                         |
 |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | 3. Sorting elements -12345 through 12345 of array Z ascending,    |
 |    leaving the rest of the items intact;                          |
 |                                                                   |
 |    %Qsort (Arr=Z, first=-12345, last=12345);                      |
 |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | 4. Sorting first 100 elements of array C descending, the rest -   |
 |    ascending:                                                     |
 |                                                                   |
 |    %Qsort (Arr=C, Seq=d, last= 100);                              |
 |    %Qsort (Arr=C, Seq=a, first=101);                              |
 |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | 5. Sorting first half of array D ascending, second half -         |
 |    descending:                                                    |
 |                                                                   |
 |    half = int((lbound(D)+hbound(D))*.5);                          |
 |    %Qsort (Arr=D, Seq=D, last=half   );                           |
 |    %Qsort (Arr=D, Seq=A, first=half+1);                           |
 |                                                                   |
 |    or without HALF and omitting Seq=A by default:                 |
 |                                                                   |
 |    %Qsort (Arr=D, Seq=D, last= (lbound(D)+hbound(D))*.5  );       |
 |    %Qsort (Arr=D,        first=(lbound(D)+hbound(D))*.5+1);       |
 |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | 6. Doing the same as in 5 without the auxiliary variable HALF     |
 |    and omitting Seq=A by default:                                 |
 |                                                                   |
 |    %Qsort (Arr=D, Seq=D, last= (lbound(D)+hbound(D))*.5  );       |
 |    %Qsort (Arr=D,        first=(lbound(D)+hbound(D))*.5+1);       |
 |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | 7. Sorting parallel arrays A B C using array B as the key array:  |
 |                                                                   |
 |    %Qsort (Arr=A B C, By=C) ;                                     |
 |                                                                   |
 |    Illustration. The following step uses array C as a key:        |
 |    ------------                                                   |
 |    data _null_;                                                   |
 |       array a(10)    ( 9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   0 );   |
 |       array b(10) $  ('a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f' 'g' 'h' 'i' 'j');   |
 |       array c(10)    ( 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 );   |
 |      %Qsort (Arr=A B C, By=C, Seq=D);                             |
 |       put A(*) / B(*) / C(*);                                     |
 |    run;                                                           |
 |                                                                   |
 |    It prints the following in the log:                            |
 |                                                                   |
 |    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9                                            |
 |    j i h g f e d c b a                                            |
 |    9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0                                            |
 |                                                                   |
 |    Note: QuickSort is an unstable algorithm, i.e. if the key array|
 |    ----------------------------------------                       |
 |    has ties (duplicate keys), subordinate array elements DO NOT   |
 |                               ---------------------------------   |
 |    retain their original relative order. This behavior is similar |
 |    ------------------------------------                           |
 |    to that of Proc Sort with NOEQUALS option.                     |
 |    The parallel array feature is most useful when it is necessary |
 |    to perform and indirect sort, i.e. with a single parallel array|
 |    containing pointers to long 'records'. For instance, instead of|
 |    giving Qsort the labor of ordering 20 parallel arrays, it is   |
 |    more efficient to store the pointers of the arrays in a single |
 |    parallel array, and then finish the entire thing using a sweep |
 |    of indirect sorting.                                           |
 |                                                                   |
 |    Note: When using LB= and HB= options with parallel arrays, ALL |
 |    ----------------------------------------                       |
 |    lower array bounds must be GE LB=value. Likewise, the upper    |
 |    bounds must all be LE than HB= value. As long as the domain of |
 |    ALL indices lies within an LB= and HB, the indexing of arrays  |
 |    on the list can be arbitrary (in particular, negative).        |
 |===================================================================|
 | Arguments:                                                        |
 |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | Parameter  Usage     Description                                  |
 |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | Arr=       Required  The name of the array (or list of any number |
 |                      of parallel arrays) to be sorted. By default,|
 |                      the first array in the list becomes the key  |
 |                      array, and the rest of the arrays are permut-|
 |                      ed accordingly.                              |
 |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | By=        Optional  The name of the key array in the list. If the|
 |                      list consists of a single array, it is the   |
 |                      key array itself - along with the rule above.|
 |                      See usage for more details.                  |
 |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | Seq=       Optional  Sorting sequence. Ascending is default. To   |
 |                      specify it explicitly, set Seq=A (any case). |
 |                      Anything else will result in the array sorted|
 |                      decsending.                                  |
 |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | LB=        Optional  The indices of the first and last array      |
 | HB=        Numeric   elements to be included into sorting. You    |
 |                      can specify any valid numeric SAS expression,|
 |                      hardcoded numeric value, or a macrovariable  |
 |                      reference resolving to any of the above. The |
 |                      values of these parms default to the lower   |
 |                      and upper bounds.                            |
 |                      Use LB= and HB= parameters if you need only  |
 |                      part of the array to be ordered, or if you   |
 |                      want different parts ordered differently,    |
 |                      which can be  achieved by issuing two or more|
 |                      consecutive calls to Qsort with LB= and HB=  |
 |                      specified accordingly (see Usage above).     |
 |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | M=         Optional  Tuning parm: The largest subpartition size   |
 |            Numeric   Quicksort attempts to partition further. Any |
 |                      subpartition LE &M is passed to the straight |
 |                      insertion sort. &M=1 corresponds to 'pure'   |
 |                      Quicksort working until all subpartitions    |
 |                      have been reduced to just 1 element. &M=9 is |
 |                      optimal. Variations from 5 to 15 affect the  |
 |                      sorting speed very slightly. Best advice as  |
 |                      to M= : Leave it alone at 9.                 |
 +===================================================================*/

   %Local _ H I J L N P Q S T W;

   %Macro Swap (I,J);
      %Local W;
      Do;
      %Do W = 1 %To &N;
         &T&W      = &&A&W(&I);
         &&A&W(&I) = &&A&W(&J);
         &&A&W(&J) =  &T&W    ;
      %End;
      End;
   %Mend Swap;

   %If %Upcase(&Seq) = %Upcase(A) %Then %Let Q = G;
   %Else                                %Let Q = L;

   %Do %Until (&&A&N EQ );
      %Let N  = %Eval(&N + 1);
      %Local A&N;
      %Let A&N = %Scan(&Arr,&N,%Str( ));
   %End;
   %Let N = %Eval(&N - 1);

   %Let _ = %Substr(%Sysfunc(Ranuni(0)),3,
      %Eval(7 - %Length(&N) + 5*(%Substr(&Sysver,1,1) GT 6)));

   %Let H = H&_; %Let I = I&_; %Let J = J&_; %Let L = L&_;
   %Let P = P&_; %Let S = S&_; %Let T = T&_; %Let Z = Z&_;

   Array &Z (0:1, 0:50) _Temporary_;

   &L = &LB; &H = &HB;

   If &H - &L GT &M Then Do &S=1 By 0 While (&S);

      &J = (&H - &L)/3; &I = &L + &J; &J = &I + &J;

      If &By(&L) &Q.T &By(&I) Then %Swap(&L,&I);
      If &By(&I) &Q.T &By(&J) Then %Swap(&I,&J);
      If &By(&J) &Q.T &By(&H) Then %Swap(&J,&H);
      If &By(&L) &Q.T &By(&I) Then %Swap(&L,&I);
      If &By(&I) &Q.T &By(&J) Then %Swap(&I,&J);
      If &By(&L) &Q.T &By(&I) Then %Swap(&L,&I);

     %If &M LE 3 %Then %Do;
      If &H - &L LE 3 Then Do;
         &L = &Z(0,&S); &H = &Z(1,&S); &S +- 1;
         Continue;
      End;
     %End;

     %Swap(&L,&I); &P = &By(&L); &I = &L;

      Do &J=&H + 1 By 0;
         Do &I=&I + 1 By  + 1 Until(&By(&I) &Q.E &P); End;
         Do &J=&J - 1 By  - 1 Until(&P &Q.E &By(&J)); End;
         If &I GE &J Then Leave;
         %Swap(&I,&J);
      End;

     %Swap(&L,&J);

      If      &H - &J GE &J - &L GT &M Then Do &S = &S + 1;
         &Z(0,&S) = &J + 1; &Z(1,&S) = &H; &H = &J - 1;
      End;
      Else If &J - &L GE &H - &J GT &M Then Do &S = &S + 1;
         &Z(0,&S) = &L; &Z(1,&S) = &J - 1; &L = &J + 1;
      End;
      Else If &J - &L GT &M GE &H - &J Then &H = &J - 1;
      Else If &H - &J GT &M GE &J - &L Then &L = &J + 1;
      Else Do;
         &L = &Z(0,&S); &H = &Z(1,&S); &S +- 1;
      End;
   End;

   %If &M = 1 %Then %Goto Exit;

   Do &J = &LB + 1 To &HB;
      If &By(&J - 1) &Q.T &By(&J) Then Do;
         &P = &By(&J);
        %Do W = 1 %To &N;
           %If &&A&W Ne &By %Then &T&W = &&A&W(&J) ; ;
        %End;
         Do &I = &J - 1 To &LB By  - 1;
            If &P &Q.E &By(&I) Then Leave;
           %Do W = 1 %To &N;
            &&A&W(&I + 1) = &&A&W(&I);
           %End;
         End;
         &By(&I + 1) = &P;
        %Do W = 1 %To &N;
           %If &&A&W Ne &By %Then &&A&W(&I + 1) = &T&W ; ;
        %End;
      End;
   End;

   %Exit: Drop &H &I &J &L &P &S T&_:;

%Mend Qsort;
```